# File takes up more space on different drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, data-transfer, copy

Ok so I have absolutely no idea why this is happening or what I can do to stop it but the summary is;

I have two drives, one that I am currently using and one that I want to use to use as a backup. Both as 2TB drives. I had copied the files across from the source drive which has 273GB remaining, however when the files finished copying, the destination drive shows only 37.4.GB free.

What the heck is going on? Can anybody explain this?!

The destination drive has fully formatted before the copy and I am certain that there is only just this one partition on the drive. I am running Windows 10 Pro 64bit Edition.

Any help or answers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Sincerely,
A very confused user

Comment: Depends on the drive formatting (allocation unit size) and if drive compression is enabled.

Comment: If I would ask this question I would add information about the OS incl. version, the file system type e.g. NTFS, exFAT or similar an the cluster size. Further your numbers are incomplete. A) copying a file of unknown size B) unknown free space on target device before copying.

Comment: beside cluster size and compression, on NTFS metadata size also affects size on disk. But the most common reason is because exFAT has bigger cluster size by default compared to NTFS. See [Same files have different “size on disk” on new drive](https://superuser.com/q/1432383/241386), [Why does “Size on disk” vary when “Size” does not with the same set of files?](https://superuser.com/q/1353064/241386)