# Same files have different "size on disk" on new drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I recently bought a 8TB HDD to replace my 1TB drive for storing my backups. However after moving the files to the new drive I noticed they take up a substantially larger amount of space on the disk, even though the true file size is the same. Both drives are formatted to be exFAT so I am not sure why the reported size is so different. Why is substantially more space being used on the new drive?

[image: File size comparison (Left is old, right is new)]

Comment: It's probably a different cluster size; might be worthwhile to use a more resilient filesystem if you're storing your backups on those drives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default cluster size for exFAT is extremely large. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1273226/241386) it's like this

```
Volume size   Cluster size
  500 GiB          128 KiB
 1000 GiB          256 KiB
 1500 GiB          512 KiB
 2000 GiB          512 KiB
 3000 GiB            1 MiB
 4000 GiB            1 MiB
 5000 GiB            2 MiB
 8000 GiB            2 MiB
10000 GiB            4 MiB
20000 GiB            8 MiB
```

Your files are 753674490827/726245 ≈
0.9897 MB on average, so on the 1 TB drive with 256 KB cluster, about ***half*** of the files take **4 clusters** (and waste almost nothing) and roughly the ***remaining half*** need **5 clusters** (and waste 1 cluster)

The average wastage is 0.5 clusters = 128 KB per file or 12.5%. The total *expected **size on disk*** is 753674490827 × 112.5% ≈ 789.7 GB which is extremely close to what's in your screenshot. However on the 8 TB disk, the clusters are 2 MB, so you're wasting ~1 MB per file, which is why the new size on disk is almost twice the total size and the previous size on disk

See

- [Please explain wasted space on an exFAT formatted external hard drive](https://superuser.com/q/365739/241386)
- [Why is exFAT's default allocation size in Windows so high?](https://superuser.com/q/1151976/241386)
- [1-byte file takes up 2 MB (yes, megabytes) on 6 TB exFAT Veracrypt volume. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/1272907/241386)
- [Why is "size on disk" much bigger than "size" when I copy data from NTFS to exFAT?](https://superuser.com/q/513835/241386)

It's also the same reason as this question [Why is there such a big difference between "Size" and "Size on disk"?](https://superuser.com/q/704218/241386)

On NTFS there are many other reasons. If you're interested read [Why does "Size on disk" vary when "Size" does not with the same set of files?](https://superuser.com/q/1353064/241386)

In short, exFAT is bad for storing small files. Either use NTFS, or reformat exFAT with a smaller cluster size (4 KB just like almost everyone else including NTFS)

Answer (score 1):

Phuclv is right.
If you are using ExFAT on a 8TB disk your cluster size will be 8MiB which means that any file will take at least 8MB of disk space, even if it's only a small txt file.

For a drive that big I would recommend ReFS (if you are using Windows 10 or 2012/2016 server) with a 4KB cluster size:

[image: ReFS Cluster Size]

or if you are looking for an even smaller cluster size go for NTFS:

[image: NTFS Cluster Size]